# Export your resume to MS Word

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Can you support exporting the resume to MS Word in Careers? Having the PDF export is great, but some employers require the MS Word format.

Comment: Yeah, but you probably didn't want to work for them anyway...

Comment: It is very depressing that many employers, especially recruiters, need MS Word formatted resumes.  PDF is a perforect format for resumes.

Comment: Why don't you convert the PDF into an Image and copy it into an MS Word document?

Comment: MS Word 2013 can import PDF files. It even manages to interpret tables!